# Spring Boot Redis Refresh/Reset Every Day or Every Hour According To TimeToLive

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I have a RedisHash code like below:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash(value = "ApiKey")
public class CreditRedis
{
    @Id
    private String id;//apiKey
    private Integer credit;

    private Long period;

    @TimeToLive
    private Long expiration;
}
```

If I set it today 10PM with 100 credit and 1Day period, then I want to  reset credit tomorrow 10PM automatically.

Example Cases:

```
new CreditRedis("1", 1000, 1Day, 1Day); -> at the end of the 1 Day credit will be reset...
new CreditRedis("1", 100, 1Hour, 1Hour); -> at the end of the 1 Hour credit will be reset...
new CreditRedis("1", 10, 10Min, 10Min); -> at the end of the 10 Min credit will be reset...
```

Is there a way to implement in on redis or spring-boot?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution:**

If spring-redis doesn't have refresh mechanism, let's implement it ourselves.

Store defaultQuote and period on redis-hash also then reset hash with these fields.

```
@RedisHash(value = "ApiKey")
public class CreditRedis
{
    @Id
    private String id;//apiKey
    private Integer maxQuote;
    private Integer remainingQuote;
    private Long expirationTime;//Don't use time-to-live, we need it always
    private Long period;//Refresh it on every day, every hour...
}
```

Update quote and expirationTime, when you need it:

```
public static Long currentExpirationTime(Long expirationTime, Long period)
{
    Long now = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    //Expiration-time should be in future
    while (expirationTime.compareTo(now) < 0)
    {
        expirationTime = expirationTime + period;
    }
    return expirationTime;
}
```

Our service will work like that:

```
    CreditRedis existCredit = getCredit(apiKey).orElse(null);
    Long currentExpirationTime = currentExpirationTime(existCredit.getExpirationTime(), existCredit.getPeriod());

    if (currentExpirationTime.compareTo(existCredit.getExpirationTime()) != 0)
    {
        existCredit.setRemainingQuote(existCredit.getMaxQuote());
    }
```